# Editing DataTable based on Query Result

Tags: c#, datatable

Had a look around and can't figure out how to do this.

I'm trying to query a datatable. I search the first column for the string value, and I need to return the integer that corresponds to it in the second column.

When I have that integer, I need to add 1 to the integer value and edit the row with the updated information.

```
 public static string hashtag_counter(string message)
    {
        int hashcounter = 0;
        DataTable hashtags = new DataTable();
        DataRow row = new DataRow();
        hashtags.Columns.Add("Hashtag", typeof(string));
        hashtags.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));


        string[] words = message.Split(' ');
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            if (word.StartsWith("#"))
            {
                if (hashtags.Columns.Contains(word))
                {
                    DataRow[] selection = hashtags.Select("Hashtag == " + word);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                row = hashtags.NewRow();
                row["Hashtag"] = word;
                row["Count"] = "1";
                hashtags.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

I can't seem to find this anywhere, so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow the requirements in your question, then your code should be like this.

```
.....
string[] words = message.Split(' ');

// Execute the loop ONLY for the required words (the ones that starts with #)
foreach (string word in words.Where(x => x.StartsWith("#")))
{
    // Search if the table contains a row with the current word in the Hashtag column
    DataRow[] selection = hashtags.Select("Hashtag = '" + word + "'");
    if(selection.Length > 0)
    {
        // We have a row with that term. Increment the counter
        // Notice that selection is an array of DataRows (albeit with just one element)
        // so we need to select the first row [0], second column [1] for the value to update
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(selection[0][1]) + 1;
        selection[0][1] = count;
    }
    else
    {
        row = hashtags.NewRow();
        row["Hashtag"] = word;
        row["Count"] = "1";
        hashtags.Rows.Add(row);
    }

}
```

Notice that if you want to Select on a string field then your need to use quotes around the search term and you don't need to use == like in C#

Comment: That's for the loop in the words. Basically, I'm checking for Hashtags in a tweet, so  `if (word.StartsWith("#"))` looks for the hashtag in the original tweet. If `word` isn't in the datatable, and starts with a hashtag, it's added to the datatable. If it's already in the datatable, i just need to add one to the count. Hope this clarifies

Comment: So you need to ignore every word that doesn't start with the `#`. A quick fix is a test that continue the loop. Probably it will be better with an IEnumerable Where condition to filter out the words to be ignored directly in the foreach loop